# Updating server Side SOAP version from 1.1 to 1.2 in a spring application

Tags: java, soap, spring-mvc, jax-ws, cxf

I am using jax-ws (cxf) based SOAP1.1 api in my springMVC based application. I have imported following cxf files in my application applicationContext.xml

```
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

and exposed my service by adding this to my project applicationContext.xml

```
 <jaxws:endpoint id="proxyService"  implementor="#proxy" address="/proxyService" />
 <bean id="proxy" class="com.aqif.service.ProxyServiceImpl" />
 <bean id="ClassModelDAO" class="com.aqif.dao.ClassModelDAOImpl"/>
```

Please let me know, what changes I need to make to upgrade from SOAP1.1 to SOAP1.2

I am using Spring 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your  for CLassModelDAO, add:

```
<property name="createSoap12Binding" value="true" />
```

This will make it look something like:

```
<bean id="ClassModelDAO" class="com.aqif.dao.ClassModelDAOImpl">
    <property name="createSoap12Binding" value="true" />
</bean>
```

You can even go as far as totally disabling 1.1 via

```
<property name="createSoap11Binding" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thnxs for your reply, can I  do something insides ClassModelDAOImpl class to do this?
regards